# Does context switch between processes invalidate the MMU(memory control unit)?

Tags: process, operating-system, cpu, mmu

This is a sentence in the PowerPoint of my system lecture, but I don't understand why context switch invalidates the MMU. I know it will invalidate the cache since the cache contains information of another process. However, as for MMU, it just maps virtual memory to physical memory. If context switch invalidates it, does this mean the MMU use different mechanism of mapping in different processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean the MMU use different mechanism of mapping in different processes?

Your conclusion is essentially right.
Each process has its mapping from virtual to physical addresses (called *context*).
The address 0x401000 for example can be translated to 0x01234567 for process A and to 0x89abcdef for process B.
Having different contexts allows for an easy [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation) of the processes, easy on demand paging and simplified relocation.

So each context switch must invalidate the TLB or the CPU would continue using the old translations.

Some pages however are *global*, meaning that they have the same translation independently of the current process address space.
For example the kernel code is mapped in the same way for every process adn thus doesn't need to be remapped.

So in the end only a part of the TLB is invalidated.
You can read how [Linux handles the process address space](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html) for a real example of applied theory.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is entirely system specific.

First of all, what they are probably referring to is invaliding the MMU cache. That assume the MMU has a cache (likely these days but not guaranteed).

When a context switch occurs, the processor has set put the MMU in a state where leftovers from the previous process would screw up the new process. If it did not, the cache would map the new process's logical pages to the old process's physical page frames.

For example, some processors use one page table for the system space and one or more other page tables for the user space. After a context switch, it would be ideal for the processor to invalidate any caching of the user space page tables but leave any caching of the system table table alone.

Note that in most processors all of this is done entirely behind the scenes. Even OS programmers do not need to deal with (or even be aware of) any flushing or invalidation of the MMU. There is a single switch process context instruction that handles everything. Other processors require the OS programmer to handle additional tasks as part of a context switch which, in some oddball processors, includes explicitly flushing the MMU cache.

Comment: Some MMUs have ASIDs, which allows one to avoid invalidating cached translations on a context switch.

Comment: Yep, there are all kinds of ways that this can be (and is) done. The bottom line is the there has to be some such mechanism (or no machine). And this is usually behind the scenes so the programmer does not even see it.